# Moving android-sdk and sdk folders to another drive

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, storage

My windows is on a 128GB ssd hard drive and it's running out of space. the folder
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android` has 2 folders `android-sdk` and `sdk` folders that use about 30GB of space.

Is it possible to move these folders to an external hard drive?

If it is possible, what changes should I make in the android studio?

Comment: Yep - Go into settings in android studio and you can select where you want the sdk to reside.

Comment: would it just move these folders too?

Comment: Nah, you'd have to copy-paste them yourself. I have an ssd primary and an hdd secondary that i use.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I do the same thing. In `Android Studio` go to Settings, select `Appearance and Behaviour` then `System Settings` then `Android SDK`

You can choose the SDK location at the top.

You'll need to copy/paste the files to that location to save yourself the downloading time.

Comment: should I copy both `sdk` and `android-sdk` folders?

Comment: It's normally `Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Copy that whole file into a new file you call `...\Sdk` and use that

Comment: what is the `android-sdk` folder because it uses 22GB of space

Comment: I'm going to guess it's a legacy from the older versions - the sdk used to be in a file named android-sdk - now it's just in the Sdk folder. The actual droid versions are found in `sdk/platforms/`

Comment: if you go into `android-sdk` - you can copy whatever you want from the `platforms` file to the `android/sdk/platforms` file - i believe that's where the bulk of the space is taken - or you can just leave it to SDK Manager and delete the old files.

Comment: Can I delete it from C after copy it to D drive ?

Comment: @Nemus yes, you can safely delete it once it has been copied to D. Just make sure you remember to point Android Studio to it

Comment: This works exactly the same way on Mac too! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I have another file named `.android` beside `.android studio` and `.gradle` files within my `C:/myuser` that uses 7GB. What is this file and can I delete or move it? where should I point to this file in Android studio?

Comment: @user3486308 that folder should just have some personalized settings for android studio like your adbkey and a build cache. If you delete it, you might need to re-connect devices for debugging and other minor annoyances, but android studio should replace that folder  automatically.

Comment: @user3486308 Among other things, that folder contains the AVD images.

Comment: Thank you , also don't forget to rename the path under "nameDevice.ini" file if you already have a device under avd folder to your new destination.

Comment: Thanks! Very simple answer! But does it affect the speed of the build after we move it from the SSD drive?

Answer (score 8):

Its very simple just copy the `sdk` to wherever you want and then change the `sdk` path in `android studio`. For that just open the **local.properties** file and set the path like this:

```
sdk.dir=your path here
```

Answer (score 3):

To keep the most used simulator in SSD drive and the others used for testing in the slow drive i created Symbolic. They are NTFS objects that appear in a folder as a sub folder but can that point to another folder on another drive.

To create then, move to `C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd` and do this:

```
mklink /d W10.1_WXGA_Tablet_API_28.avd d:\androidSimulators\W10.1_WXGA_Tablet_API_28.avd
```

MDLink info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/67870/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-hard-links-and-directory-junctions).

If using Linux based systems you can also do this with linked directories.

For windows 10 users, emulators are stored by default at here:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd
```

Comment: The question is about moving the Android SDK, not the AVDs.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii, yes but the goal is to release space. AVDs are huge and come inside SDK folder

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a link in C:/Users//AppData/ named Android pointing to D:/Users//AppData/Android doing so all android data are in another drive not in the main drive look how much space I saved doing this.

[image]

To create a link pointing to another drive first open your terminal in the directory you want to create a link.

I will use PowerShell, use this command to do it

```
New-Item -Path 'C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Android'  -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value 'D:/Users/<username>/AppData/Android'
```