# Change the default Users folder in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Been trying in vain to change the default `Users` folder drive **C** to drive **G** as drive C has very little space left.

These answers helped to some extent, in that, I was successful only moving the `.gradle` folder:

- [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726529/moving-android-sdk-and-sdk-folders-to-another-drive)
- [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place)

But in spite of following them verbatim, **Android Studio 3.0** makes in **drive C**, the `.android`, `.AndroidStudio3.0` folders **and** populates them with its stuff everytime it restarts.

Here's the `idea.properties` file:

```
# custom Android Studio properties
idea.config.path=G:/Users/Nani/.AndroidStudio3.0/config
idea.system.path=G:/Users/Nani/.AndroidStudio3.0/system
```

...and the system environment variables:

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOME = G:\Users\Nani
GRADLE_USER_HOME = G:\Users\Nani
```

Has anything changed in this regard with **Android Studio 3**? Kindly advice; thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the solution is simple. Followed these steps:

1. Closed project and from the `Configure` menu in the Studio Welcome screen, set the Android SDK folder to `G:\Users\Nani\AppData\Local\Android`
2. Allowed Studio to download the SDK again into the new location (copying the existing SDK proved painful)
3. Allowed the `idea.properties` file and the system environment variables (as in the question), to remain

Now, drive **C** is sufficiently free and all Studio download activities happen in drive **G**.

Thanks to all who looked in.